# Union of Intersections

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to prove that $S\cup(S\cap T)=S$ and the dual statement $S\cap(S\cup T)=S$ for a class, and have gotten stuck with my proof.

$$
S\cup(S\cap T)
$$
$$
=\{x|x\in S\lor x\in (S\cap T)\}
$$
$$
=\{x|x\in S\lor (x\in S\land ]x\in T)\}
$$
$$
=\{x|(x\in S\lor x\in S)\land (x\in S\lor x\in T)\}
$$

Any help on where to go from here would be appreciated.

Comment: A lot of times, when trying to show that two sets are equal, it is easier to show inclusion from both directions one step at a time. i.e If you want to show that $A=B$  then show that $A\subseteq B$  and that $B\subseteq A$. Take an arbitrary element from $A$ and show that it is in $B$ and then the other way round.

I recommend you to try that before looking at the answers

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$S\cup(S\cap T)$$

Let $R = S\cap T$

We know $R\subseteq S$ since the intersection of some set $S$ with any other set is a subset of $S$.

We also know the union of $S$ and any subset of $S$--including $R$--is $S$, i.e. $R\cup S=S$.

Therefore, $S\cup(S\cap T)=S$

Comment: I will need to prove the second statement as well to be able to use it. How would I do that?